# How to activate Bootstrap Tab and open tab content programmatically using Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I simply redirected to Profile page with router fragment (/profile#favorites) where favorite is a Bootstrap tab component. By default, first tab is active and favorite tab is 2 here in my case which I want to programmatically activate retriving fragment name from the url.

I got the fragment from url by:

```
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
  console.log('fragment : ', fragment);
});
```

My tabs structure is :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#myPets"> My Pets</a> </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#favorites">Favorites</a></li>
    <li *ngIf="!userDetails?.isSocialSiteUser">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#changePassword">Change Password</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#account"> Account</a></li> -->
    <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#meets">Upcoming Meet and Greets</a> </li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#myDeals" *ngIf="myDeals.length">My Deals</a> </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="myPets" class="tab-pane overflow-y-500-x-hide fade in active" #myPets>
    ...
    </div>

    <div id="favorites" class="overflow-y-500-x-hide tab-pane fade" #favorites>
    <sfl-profile-favorites></sfl-profile-favorites>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

Now I don't know how to activate the favorites tab. Maybe this can be achieved by toggling the `in active` class, but how can I remove from all other tabs and add to particular tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store fragment and apply `active` class condition in template file

```
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
  this.currentFragment = fragment //store somewhere
});
```

In template file `[ngClass]="{'class': true}"`

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active': currentFragment === '/profile#myPets'}">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#myPets"> My Pets</a> </li>

<li [ngClass]="{'active': currentFragment === '/profile#favorites'}">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#favorites">Favorites</a></li>

<div id="favorites" class="overflow-y-500-x-hide tab-pane fade" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': currentFragment === '/profile#favorites'}"
     #favorites>.....</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Very simple, but was out of my mind! Thanks!

Comment: One issue now facing is, when I open any other tab manually and then go to favorites programatically using fragment, the old tab content stays and favorites tab content is appended on top of it.

Comment: [update] I removed the data-toggle attributes from nav-tabs and instead, I put routerlink with fragment which then worked fine for me.

Comment: does anyone have stackblitz demo ?. Im trying with given solution . seems not working form me ..!! @Chenna